# ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'sqoop' 'import' '<EOF>' while importinf table from oracle to hadoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to import 1 table from oracle to hadoop. here is my query

```
sqoop import--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@cweprda:1521/cwe_badge --table 
A608232_MYVOICE_WITH_INT_ID --username ******--password ****** -m 1 \
--create-hive-table--hive-import--hive-table 
 aads.A608232_MYVOICE_WITH_INT_ID 
--hive-overwrite--warehouse-dir /tmp/a608232;
```

I am Not able to get what am I doing wrong here. Please advice 
here is error sc 
[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: ohh sorry will change it

Comment: You're missing a white space between `import`and `--connect`

Comment: It still gives same error . I tried with white space intially. After I tried removing it.

Comment: Or can anyone give me correct syntax how to do it!

Comment: people please stop downvoting question. I know might be simple one but I am new to this hence asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are at the Hive/Beeline CLI, not the shell. There is a difference between `>` vs `$`

Type `quit;`, or logout and back into the terminal to get a fresh session, then run `sqoop`. And that is just `sqoop`. Make sure it doesn't throw an error, and prints the sqoop usage output.

Then, continue with the command and check your spacing in the arguments.

Comment: Thank you that worked. using it for first time so i didnt know